# Can't install adhoc ipa on iTunes Windows

Tags: xcode4, ios5, windows-xp, itunes

i am trying to build a adhoc distribution ipa.

I succesfully created an ipa and installed it on my iPhone 3GS in my Mac via iTunes.

Then I wanted to install this app in my iPod but I haven't success.

This is what I did:

In my Mac

1. I went to member center.
2. Added my iPod as a device
3. Edited my provisioning profile, added my iPod device, and downloaded the new provisioning profile.
4. In Xcode > Organizer > Devices deleted my previous provisioning profile
5. In Downloads clicked in my new provisioning profile to add it to xcode
6. Product > Archive

In my PC (Windows XP)

1. I've downloaded iPhone Configuration Utility
2. In iPhone Configuration Utility I've added my provisioning profile to my iPod
3. In iPhone Configuration Utility I've tried to install my app to my iPod but I had an error: "kamdundefinederror"
4. I've added my ipa to iTunes and tried to sincronize, but I had an error "La aplicacion no se ha instalado en el iphone porque no es compatible con este ipod" (something like "The application wasnt installed in the iphone because it's not compatible with this iPod"

Some data about versions:

- I am using xcode 4
- In my project > info I have iOS deployment target: 4.2
- In build settings i have Base SDK "Latest iOS (iOS 5.0)"
- My iPhone 3GS os version is 5.0.1
- My iPod os version is 4.2.1

Does anyone have any idea why I can't install my app in iPod? Is it because my iPod os version? I am making any mistake?

Comment: Write something more  about this iPod (model etc.)

Comment: My iPod is and iPod 3G with 8gb.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, check architectures in build settings of  your project.
If you have here only "armv7" this is the reason, you should have "armv6 armv7"